# Can’t find C header files on Mac OS X

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, osx-yosemite, icc

I upgraded to Yosemite, and now all my compilers (from the command line—gcc and icc) are giving me errors like: cannot open source file “ctype.h"

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I need to reinstall the compilers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not sure what’s going on here, but after updating to Xcode 6.1.1 and installing the associated command line tools, icc seems like it can now find the system headers. Now having a separate issue with gcc, will post separately…